# How do I reformat HDD to NTFS with Ubuntu on a bootable USB

Tags: live-usb, ntfs

So I need to install Windows on my Hard Drive and I'm trying to use Ubuntu to reformat the HDD to NTFS. These are the steps I will take:

- Create a bootable USB with Ubuntu
- Boot from USB
- ???
- Remove USB, now boot with my Windows install disc.

The third step is where I'm confused. Once I boot from USB, how do I make the HDD into NTFS? I did a google search and I'm pretty confused with the results. I really don't want to mess up the HDD.

What do I do after?

Comment: If you simply want to install Windows and overwrite anything on the hdd, you do not need to reformat, just choose the appropriate option during windows install.

Comment: @ToDo I tried, it said it wasn't NTFS.

Comment: There's an advanced option somewhere that permits you to create a new partition table and a new NTFS partition. Don't remember the details. You must press an F? key at some point. Sorry for this sketchy instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Open GParted and use this option:

[image]

Comment: I assume I have to install this after I boot the usb?

Comment: This program is implemented in ubuntu live ;)